# WAS LDAP Query configuration for two different active directory with same user id presents

Tags: active-directory, ldap, was

When we try to implement SSO we found that same user id present in the two different Active directory. By the i need to fetch only from the particular AD. This authentication not performed as expected.
e.g

AD1 - Userid 12345
AD2 - Userid 12345

Our query not fetching up the AD1 details and group permission since the id present in other groups as well. Could you please suggest me anything on this. please?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this you should add a drop down box to the login form where the user can select the domain to log into (like on old windows) and/or allow for fully qualified login names such as `DOMAIN\username` and `username@domain.local` (like new windows).